# python - how to do this special sum in the most efficient way

Tags: python, performance

I need to calculate a peculiar sum, and what I tried so far might not be the most efficient strategy; I wonder if anyone can suggest better ones.

```
import time

N = 10000

Uf = ([0]*2) + [1/f for f in range(2,N+1)]
```

This part never changes (`N` may be different, or the function of `f` that defines `Uf`, but all the terms are calculated).

```
fs = [[2]*1000, [9998]*2, [5]*2000, [9995]*1, [10]*585, [20]*878,
      [50]*2580, [77]*1487, [1100]*5454, [2300]*4047, [3700]*5471]

Ff = [0]*(N+1)

for l in fs:
    Ff[l[0]] = len(l)
```

`fs` is presented in a different way in my real application, but it amounts to the same: there is a list of values of `f`, each repeated a given number of times.
E.g. here `f = 2` is repeated 1000 times, `f = 9998` is repeated 2 times, etc.
I store the frequency of each value of `f` into a list `Ff`.
I define `Ff` this way because I want to be able to obtain the frequency of `f` simply by `Ff[f]`.
And I fill `Ff` with 0's everywhere else, because during the further calculations that I need to do, the frequency of many values of `f` changes (increases or decreases) a large number of times, and having all list positions already filled with a number makes this much easier.

Here is the sum that I need to calculate (`S`):

```
S = sum([(Ff[f]+Ff[N-f])*Uf[f] for f in range(2,N)])
print(S)
# 1085.5709951104413
%timeit S = sum([(Ff[f]+Ff[N-f])*Uf[f] for f in range(2,N)])
# 3.93 ms ± 327 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

At first I thought that the (relatively) slow performance was due to the fact that I summed a lot of 0's that I could have left out.
So I tried introducing a condition:

```
S = sum([(Ff[f]+Ff[N-f])*Uf[f] for f in range(2,N) if (Ff[f] + Ff[N-f] > 0)])
print(S)
# 1085.5709951104413
%timeit S = sum([(Ff[f]+Ff[N-f])*Uf[f] for f in range(2,N) if (Ff[f] + Ff[N-f] > 0)])
# 2.53 ms ± 120 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

OK, it helped, but was not really Earth-shattering.

Using a logical 'or' condition instead of a sum to identify the valid terms actually made things slightly worse:

```
S = sum([(Ff[f]+Ff[N-f])*Uf[f] for f in range(2,N) if ((Ff[f] > 0) | (Ff[N-f] > 0))])
print(S)
# 1085.5709951104413
%timeit S = sum([(Ff[f]+Ff[N-f])*Uf[f] for f in range(2,N) if ((Ff[f] > 0) | (Ff[N-f] > 0))])
# 3.02 ms ± 175 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

In the end I could confirm that, if the terms to sum were identified a priori (externally), the speed would increase enormously:

```
f_on = [f for f,_ in enumerate(Ff) if ((Ff[f] > 0) | (Ff[N-f] > 0))]
S = sum([(Ff[f]+Ff[N-f])*Uf[f] for f in f_on])
print(S)
# 1085.5709951104413
%timeit S = sum([(Ff[f]+Ff[N-f])*Uf[f] for f in f_on])
# 6.12 µs ± 327 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

The obvious next step was to give up the 'easy way' of list `Ff`, and use a dictionary instead, whose keys (values of `f`) would automatically identify which `f`'s were relevant (but not as obviously as it may seem, see below).

```
# Dictionary method

Fr_dict = dict()
for l in fs:
    Fr_dict[l[0]] = len(l)
```

In each term of the sum I would be calling `Fr_dict[f]` and `Fr_dict[N-f]`; but obviously they are not always both defined.
To avoid key errors, I defined a function:

```
def Fr(f):
    if f in Fr_dict:
        Fr = Fr_dict[f]
    else:
        Fr = 0
    return Fr
```

Then:

```
S = sum([(Fr(f)+Fr(N-f))*Uf[f] for f in set(list(Fr_dict.keys())+[N-f for f in Fr_dict.keys()])])
print(S)
# 1085.570995110441
%timeit S = sum([(Fr(f)+Fr(N-f))*Uf[f] for f in set(list(Fr_dict.keys())+[N-f for f in Fr_dict.keys()])])
# 16.3 µs ± 452 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Note that it is not sufficient to use the keys in the dictionary to identify which `f` terms to sum: I also need the `f`'s for which `Fr_dict` contains `N-f`. And to avoid any unwanted duplication, I used `set`.

All this has a cost: the best my dictionary method can do is about 16.3 µs, i.e. about 155 times faster than the 2.530 ms of the best non-dictionary method.
This might be satisfactory for my purposes, although I fear that going for larger `N` might start to show some cracks.
And, being a relative novice in `Python`, I can't help wondering if I am not barking up the wrong tree.

> **What do you think? Could there be any alternative methods, or just different manipulations of the dictionary, that would perform even better?**

Thanks

Comment: First thing that sticks out is that you are passing a list comprehension to `sum`, this unnecessarily creates a list that is then discarded, you should use generator comprehensions instead. `sum(x for x in iterator)` vs `sum([x for x in iterator])`

Comment: It seems like your 'get with default' dictionary is a hand-written implementation of [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), which also includes helpful methods to filter only positive-valued keys, and in my experience, is slightly faster than a manual 'get with default' due to some implementation tricks. Also, NumPy in general seems perfect for your use case

Comment: Note that using *Numpy* and especially *Numba* may help to speed up your computations.

Comment: @IainShelvington : thanks! I tried what you suggested, and while time-wise it did not make a difference for this example, I can imagine it is more efficient for several reasons.

Comment: @kcsquared : thanks. I suppose this is in the same spirit as Alain T.'s answer below. I admit it, I was trying to do this with base functionalities, partly by design, and mostly because I did not know of / did not go and search for more advanced packages that did what I needed. As for numpy - OK; I might have to leave it for another time, as I have already written quite a bit of code by now, based on standard python stuff, and I cannot really go and change everything so fundamentally, at least in the short term. The collections.Counter vs dictionary part I can probably still manage to change.

Comment: @user6376297 If your ranges are all (2, N), you should be able to get an equivalent sum with `S = sum(value * (Uf[key] + Uf[N-key]) for key, value in Fr_dict.items())`. I would also kindly mention that it would be very helpful for reading and understanding your question if you changed all of your variable names: Trying to parse 'l' or 'f' as every loop variable, or remember what Uf, fs, Ff, Fr, etc. are (and Fr being a function and local variable inside that function) means readers might have to copy and rewrite all of your names to follow your explanation.

Comment: @kcsquared : OK, sure, if that is useful I will do it next time. What would I need to change the variable names to?

Comment: @user6376297 A proper answer to that question would occupy at least an hour; the best I can offer is that names should tell a story, and match what you call things in real life. So if 'fs' is short for something you call frequencies, just say 'frequencies'. If 'Ff' is really a short way of saying 'frequency of frequencies', use that name or find a more descriptive word. Abbreviations force human readers (including the original coder) to build a mental lookup table from strings of characters to actual concepts

Comment: @kcsquared : OK, I see, thank you, that's what I had understood, but I wanted to be sure not to misinterpret your advice. And it makes perfect sense; that's what I would have normally done. Except that someone once told me the exact opposite; he said "keep your variable names short, people are annoyed by long descriptive names". Not being a programmer by training, I didn't know any better :/ BTW I still want to try your simplified formula.

Comment: I can confirm that the simplified formula does not seem to give the same result as the original one. Consider for instance `N = 5; Fr_dict = {1: 5, 2: 1, 3: 5, 4: 2, 5: 2}`. Original formula: `(Fr(2)+Fr(3))*U(2) + (Fr(3)+Fr(2))*U(3) + (Fr(4)+Fr(1))*U(4) = (1+5)*1/2+(5+1)*1/3+(2+5)*1/4 = 6.75`. New formula: `(Uf(1)+Uf(4))*Fr(1) + (Uf(2)+Uf(3))*Fr(2) + (Uf(3)+Uf(2))*Fr(3) + (Uf(4)+Uf(1))*Fr(4) + (Uf(5)+Uf(0))*Fr(5) = (0+1/4)*5 + (1/2+1/3)*1 + (1/3+1/2)*5 + (1/4+0)*2 + (1/5+0)*2 = 7.15`.

Comment: @user6376297 That's true, since `Fr(N)` (here `Fr(5)`) is not ever included in the original sum. There's also `Fr(N-1)` which shouldn't get multiplied by `Uf[1]` since the sum is in `range(2, N)`. I believe those are the only exceptions, but the summation bounds do change when you swap indices

Comment: `Uf[0]` and `Uf[1]` are both 0, so that is not a problem. Your formula indeed differs from the original one by a single term `Fr(N) * Uf[N]`, but, as far as I can tell, only if the dictionary contains all frequencies from 1 to N. If the dictionary misses some terms, I really cannot tell how this will pan out. It's a pity, because computationally speaking your formula would be far better :/

Comment: Actually your formula works, and it only differs from the original one by `Fr(N) * Uf[N]` in all possible cases, regardless of `Ff`. Even worse, I looked back at my records, and found that your formula was the starting point, and then for some reason I did the opposite sum distribution and change of variables that you probably did, yielding the less efficient one I mentioned in my post. Go figure why I thought it was better to sum the frequencies than to sum the U's... and especially how I forgot about that... anyway thank you very much for your input, I upvoted your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using Counter (from collections) instead of a plain old dictionary.  this will allows you to store the counts efficiently yet obtain zero when you access Ff[f] for a non-existant entry.

You could actually use if for `fs` instead of storing counts separately:

```
fs = Counter({2:1000, 9998:2, 5:2000, 9995:1, 10:585, 20:878,
             50:2580, 77:1487, 1100:5454, 2300:4047, 3700:5471})
```

You could also pre-compute another dictionary from this one to hold the value of fs[f]+fs[N-f] if you are accessing that often:

```
Frs = Counter({ f:s+fs[N-f] for f,s in Fs.items() if s>0 and Fs[N-f]>0})
```

Then getting the multiplier for Uf[f] would only require a single dictionary access: `Frs[f]*Uf[f]`

Comment: Thank you; I tried your suggestion, and as far as time is concerned, it did not change much. So the fact that I define a function to stop key errors, and then call that function, does not impact the execution time. Did you have anything different in mind regarding identifying the `f`'s to handle (instead of `set(list(fs.keys())+[N-f for f in fs.keys()])`) ? Unfortunately I cannot pre-define `Frs` as you indicated, because `N` changes at each iteration. Remaking the `Counter` at each iteration would probably be just as expensive, wouldn't it?

Comment: I don't have any fundamental improvements to suggests, but to shave off a bit from calculations, when you compute your sums, try to avoid/reduce the number of indexing references.  For example `[ (fn+fs[N-f])*Uf[f] for f,fn in Fs.items()]` automatically excludes zeros and requires only one index reference as opposed to the four you are making in your examples. Also, if you calling the sum computation often with the same f and N, you may want to look into `lru_cache` from functools.

Comment: BTW when both Fs[f] and Fs[N-f] have a non-zero value,  the sum will count the pairing twice.  Is that intentional/desirable ?

Comment: Alain T. : yes it is intentional. BTW I noticed an error in my code. It works for this example, but in fact for a more general case it should be `set(list(fs.keys())+[N-f for f in fs.keys()]) if ((f >= 2) & (f <= N-1))`, as those were the limits of the summation in the original formula.